# session variable inaccessible on subsequent page

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm using a PHP session variable and it's not working as I'd expect. On one page I have:

```
<?php
session_start();
$car_details = Array(
    "make"  => 'ford',
    "model" => 'some car'
    );

$_SESSION['car_details'] = $car_details;
echo var_dump($_SESSION['car_details']);  
   //array (size=2)
   //   'make' => string 'ford' (length=4)
   //   'model' => string 'some car' (length=8)
?>
```

This works as I'd expect. On the next page in the same directory however, I try to add an element to the array. Not only does the element overwrite the entire array, it doesn't print the values stored in the first page at all:

```
<?php
session_start();

$car_details = $_SESSION['car_details'];
echo var_dump($car_details);
    //null

$car_details["used"] = true;
$_SESSION['car_details'] = $car_details;
echo var_dump($_SESSION['car_details']);
   //array (size=1)
   //    'used' => boolean true

?>
```

This is not the behavior I would expect at all. I can see that maybe I should unshift the "used" element or something, but why would the previously stored array not show up on the subsequent page?

Comment: have you tried outputting `$car_details` directly after you set it? if so, does that print the appropriate results?

Comment: It might be worth setting PHP to a more appropriate level of error reporting - your current code will emit a couple of `E_NOTICE`s.

Comment: @SamuelCook I do that in the last line of the first block, no? Do you mean somewhere else?

Comment: oh nevermind i see it.

Comment: @SamuelCook what about the line `$car_details["used"] = true;`? Will this overwrite the entire array?

Comment: Random note: You don't need to `echo` the result of `var_dump()` - it generates output on it's own, and doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though there is something wrong with your session configuration. Your code for setting and passing around the session data looks fine, and I've verified that it works on my machine.

To troubleshoot this, I'd start looking at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools (my favourite at the moment is Google Chrome's, [info here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)). You're going to be looking for either a session ID being appended to the URL query string, or, most likely, a cookie sent by your browser, probably named `PHPSESSID`.

This value tells PHP which session ID to look up for you. Without it, calling `session_start()` will generate a new session, which appears to be what is happening in your case.